# How to add already created .a file while creating .a file

Tags: static, static-libraries, unix-ar

can anyone tell how can I include already existing `.a` file while creating `.a` with this?

```
ar rcs libcrypt.a
```

I need to add `libssl.a` and `libcrypto.a` files together into a `libcrypt.a` file. Can you help me to solve this?

Comment: perhaps `ar rcs libcrypt.a libssl.a libcrypto.a`?

Comment: @geza: perhaps not.  While your command would run, it would put the files `libssl.a` and `libcrypto.a` into the (new) `libcrypt.a` archive.  That much would work, but the linker would be looking for `.o` files and not complete `.a` files in the library; it wouldn't find any symbols in `libcrypt.a`.  You have to add the object files as object files.   (You can store source code and other files in archives if you wish.  Very few people actually do so, but that was originally an intended use for the `ar` program.)

Answer (score 1):

[`man ar`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ar) tells you how to extract
all the members from an archive, and it tells you how to insert members
into an archive.

So extract all the members from `libssl.a` and `libcrypto.a`
and insert them all into `libcrypt.a`, taking care to do the extracting
in an empty directory.

```
$ mkdir scrap
$ cd scrap
$ ar -x ../libssl.a
$ ar -x ../libcrypto.a
$ ar rcs ../libcrypt.a *
$ cd ..
$ rm -r scrap/
```

Comment: The one-liners leave a lot of debris (extracted object files) in the current directory.  The variant using the sub-directory is much cleaner, therefore.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Quite true. Didn't consider the debris.